# What does "a star " symbolize here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

From the poem ["Opportunity"](https://allpoetry.com/poem/8619891-Opportunity-by-Walter-Malone) by Walter Malone:

> Each morning gives thee wings to flee from hell,
> Each night **a star** to guide thy feet to heaven.

What does "a star" symbolize here? Can anyone tell me the meanings of this verse?

Comment: There is a stack exchange [literature.se] with questions of interpretation explictly on topic.

Answer (score 9):

On a literal level, stars used to be commonly used for guidance and navigation (primarily on the sea, but also eg. by the three Wise Men in Christian tradition), so it's a natural example of "something to guide you somewhere".

Metaphorically, the star represents the titular *opportunity*. The message of the poem seems to be that you shouldn't dwell in mourning or regret, because every day gives you new chances to achieve something - new *wings to flee from hell* (an opportunity to escape the despair) and a new *star to guide you to heaven* (an opportunity to progress and move forward towards your goal).